# Migrating Magento from Magento 1 to Magento 2

Tags: magento2, migration

I got two e-commerce stores running on Magento version 1.9.3.8, what are the difficulties I am going to face in future, if I don't upgrade them to Magento 2, the business said they don't want to upgrade to Magento 2.

It would be helpful for me if anyone specifies all the problems we are going to face if we don't upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

As such there are no difficulties you will face in near future, as Magento haven't announced the official date to shut down the support of Magent 1.x yet so you will continuously get security updates from Magento.

Magento have mentioned in one article that before they will shut down support for M1 they will let us know minimum 18 months before, so you will still get enough time to move to M2.

For reference you can see this article:

https://magento.com/blog/magento-news/ongoing-magento-1-support

Comment: Hi , what about this article  ,https://advantec.co.uk/support-magento-1-end/

Comment: The one I have shared is from official Magento's article, all other one is not correct, as the first line of article is saying

"I’d like to directly address some misconceptions we’re hearing about Magento."

Comment: Please help to vote up if you think it is beneficial. Thanks